# Execute flash message if js and not it html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I use cancan for role based authorization.

On access denied I have this in the application_controller

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
 flash[:notice] = flash_helper("Access denied.")
 render :template => "shared/access_denied"
end
```

The problem is that sometimes it have to generate a js response and other times a html response.

I want a conditional that execute the flash notice when it is a js response and not when it is a html reponse.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe there is a property on the `request` object that have this kind of information. I just don't remeber which on is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MurifoX for pointing me in the right direction. This code does it

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
 if request.format == "text/javascript"
   flash[:notice] = flash_helper("Access denied.")
 end
 render :template => "shared/access_denied"
end
```